# Java: Is there a right way to use static volatile variables?

Tags: java, concurrency

I want to have a flag that could be accessible to read/write from different threads without any problem of dirty values. Is it enough to make it static volatile?

```
static volatile boolean flag;
```

Comment: I am not sure if it is enough or not, but I recommend to use [`AtomicBoolean`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html) instead.

Comment: I would avoid static mutable fields whenever possible. Instead I would use an AtomicBoolean which is passed to the threads you want to flag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this is not enough if you need an action like this:

```
volatile int v = 0;

Thread 1:
v++;

Thread 2:
v--;
```

Ideally you want v=0 when you execute the above code, but this is what is really happening (a composite action):

```
Thread 1:
r1 = v;
r2 = r1 + 1;
v = r2;

Thread 2:
r3 = v;
r4 = r3 - 1;
v = r4;
```

And both the threads will give values of 1 and -1 respectively. Source:  [Volatile Does Not Mean Atomic!](http://jeremymanson.blogspot.com/2007/08/volatile-does-not-mean-atomic.html)

If you need guaranteed consistent result in a mulithreaded scenario, you should be using Atomic classes in Java as @Eng.Fouad pointed out.

In the case of a boolean too, compare-and-set will be helpful from AtomicBoolean class than using volatile.

Comment: Yes, it is for operations that read, calucalte and save data. But is it correct to use for only read\write operations as boolean vars?

Comment: I didn't get that. Are you asking is volatile correct to use for r/w ops? (I just answered that)

Comment: No, I mean that we have static volatile flag. Then I mark it as false, another thread read it, and other thread marks it as true. In this case will I get a dirty values or not?

Comment: ah, I see. Well, volatile will work, but you will need to make sure that you are the owner and its modification is limited to 1 thread (Example, a flag like shutdownthissystem can be volatile). But if you have a flag which can modified by any thread at random and read again by some other thread, you should be using AtomicBoolean.

Answer (score 3):

It's tempting but avoid code like that.

In a simple scenario, this seems to works because `boolean` doesn't allow any math operations (you can only assign values to it). But you rarely have simple cases. Eventually, you will need

```
if(flag) {
    flag = false;
}
```

and this code will sometimes break. Therefore, as suggested by the other answers, you should use the `java.util.concurrent.Atomic`* classes.